# How to connect with github repository in eclipse?

Tags: github, dictionary, repository, eclipse-kepler

I have created a repository in https://github.com. And installed `eclipse Kepler` as the editor.  I want to commit my local file to this remote repository. How to achieve this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

> EDIT

I followed your links and got the following error. Can you assist further please?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've just done this for the first time myself and found these two tutorials very helpful. They both refer to EGit which I believe comes bundled with Kepler, I certainly didn't have to install it myself.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide

http://benjsicam.me/blog/how-to-setup-eclipse-git-plugin-egit-for-github-part-1-tutorial/ (Link dead, a copy of the article can be found [here](http://thisdotlife.com/2013/05/26/how-to-setup-eclipse-git-plugin-egit-for-github-part-1-tutorial/) or on the [wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20140625082056/http://benjsicam.me/blog/how-to-setup-eclipse-git-plugin-egit-for-github-part-1-tutorial/))

Comment: Thanks for the response. I followed the provided links. Check I have edited the question.

Comment: @Su123 I didn't get that error myself so couldn't say for sure but where it mentions the Network Connection -> SSH2 settings, did you set-up the DSA keys and save the public key in GitHub correctly? I guess that would be the place to start lookings. Otherwise, I don't know, sorry.